# Incompatible class of models when using the models trained in maven project A to maven project B under the same Maven dependency

Tags: maven, weka, prediction

I have a big maven project A, where I use weka library to train the models. Now I create another small maven project B using the same maven dependency as A, and want to use the models trained in A.

When I use SerializationHelper class to read the models and use the models to predict for new instance in project B, it encounters some errors like incompatible class of the models(see picture below). I just wonder whether there is a way to use the models trained in A in project B if the maven dependency for A and B is the same. Or I have to retrain the models in B and use it in B. Thanks.

[New exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQ0oK.jpg)

> ```
> Classifier cls = (Classifier) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read(model);
> double clsLabel = cls.classifyInstance(Data.instance(i));
> ```

[image: New Exception]

Answer (score 0):

SerializationHelper is supposed to used for different projects and different machines. Your mistake should be elsewhere. Try following suggestions.

1. Your project A and project B has different java compiler settings. May be A is 5.0 and B is 8.0.
2. Your model file is corrupted. Try it first in project where you saved it, Project A.
3. You are saving different object not Classifier. Try to print out your class name to system.out and see.

> ```
>  Object objModel = weka.core.SerializationHelper.read(model);
>  String modelClassName = objModel.getClass().getCanonicalName();
>  System.out.println(objModel);
> ```

4. For Weka classifiers, arff files' headers should be same, exactly same. If your training and testing arff file headers are not same. You will have problems.

Comment: Hi, Atilla thanks for your quick response. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Regarding to your three points, I have double checked the java compiler settings are the same. And also the model file works fine in project A. But I just a bit confused about the third points. What do you mean by print out the class name? Do you mean print out the class name of the model file or what? Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Atila, thanks for your quick response. I find when I recreate the new project B and did what I have done in the past, the exception message is different from what I posted before. I have added the new exception image. Could you look at it and suggest any ideas here? Thanks.